# c# Возврат Null терминированной строки из ReadOnlySpan<byte>

Tags: c#, .net-5

Есть `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`  в нём на определённом месте содержится строка которую надо извлечь. Длинну строки заранее мы не знаем, но знаем что она null terminated и знаем точный offset начала этой строки в массиве.
в с++ я бы сделал так:

```
string favorite(&buffer[600]);
```

Для C# пришлось сделать так:

```
var indexInSlice = bytes.Slice(600).IndexOf(Convert.ToByte(0x00));
return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes.Slice(600, indexInSlice));
```

Нет ли более удобного способа получить эту строку?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь что-то десериализировать?

Comment: @VladD нет, это hex файл с параметрами одного девайса

Comment: чем-то вы сложным занимаетесь :) чем вам так C# приглянулся? для этих целей, казалось бы, больше подходит C/C++?

Comment: @return хочется сделать и под C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С вашим кодом все впорядке, ну разве что можно использовать `System.Range` вместо `.Slice()`

```cs
ReadOnlySpan<byte> stringBytes = bytes[600..];
int index = stringBytes.IndexOf((byte)0);
return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stringBytes[..index]));
```

Есть у меня еще такой метод, который в принципе сути не меняет

```cs
private static string ReadStringZ(ReadOnlySpan<byte> buffer)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < buffer.Length && buffer[i] != 0)
        i++;
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer[..i]);
}
```

```cs
string text = ReadStringZ(data[600..]);
```

Достаточно быстро работает, не требует дополнительно памяти, из пачки байт сразу получается строка.

А вообще есть такой класс `BinaryReader`, если у вас поток данных, то их можно считывать вообще посимвольно (сразу в ASCII) сразу в строку. Просто открываете файл, подсовываете файловый поток в `BinaryReader` и читаете сразу в нужные типы данных. Метод выше - копия моего метода, выполняющая ту же функцию, но только там у меня `ReadOnlySpan<char>`, и я возвращаю значение как `new string(buffer[..i])`.